# Antonym for diminutive name

Tags: antonyms

Is there any antonym for "diminutive" when specifically used for names?
For example:

```
Joe is a diminutive of Joseph
Joseph is a ______ of Joe
```

Comment: Since this is not a binary opposition, there is no clear "opposite". To start with, _Joseph_ is not "a _____" of anything. It's ***THE*** original source for _Joe_; there aren't any others, so _a_ is incorrect. Second, there is an opposite for morphological diminutive, like _-ito_ in Spanish; Spanish also has an Augmentative suffix, _-on_, as in _sillon_ 'couch', from _silla_ 'chair'. But augmentative just makes something big, like a diminutive makes it small -- it doesn't trace anything back to its source. You can use the word _source_ or the word _root_; they mostly mean the same here.

Comment: Wow. All that over a/the?  I would argue that Joe could also be a diminutive of Josef.  In any event, there are definitely 1-1, 1-N, N-1 and N-M relationships between names and their diminutives and Joe/Joseph was only an example.

Comment: You could say that *Joseph* is his *full*, *complete*, *long*, or *actual* name. But none of those are opposites in an exact sense. (The first comment here is correct if you're looking for something that specific.)

Comment: From what I can tell, in English, you form **diminutives** of words by using a suffix – e.g. **dog** becomes **doggie** or doggy – and you form **augmentatives** by using a prefix – e.g. **master** becomes **grandmaster**. For given names however, you form diminutives by clipping the original name – e.g. Alexander becomes Alex, Barbara becomes Barb – but to form augmentatives of given names, you don't use a prefix. Instead, you prepend the original name with another word – e.g. Joseph becomes Big Joseph, or more commonly Joe becomes Big Joe. Hence, augmentative of Joseph is not Big Joe.

Comment: This is in contrast to Slavic languages, where we do everything with suffixes. We have many ways to form both diminutives and augmentatives. Diminutive of **Nikola** (from Greek name Nikolaos) is **Nikolica** or Nikolče (common given name in Macedonia). There are in fact many diminutives of Nikola. Augmentative form of the same name is **Nikoletina**. Unlike in English, it's typically a single word, not two.

Comment: To me, Alex is just a shorter version of Alexander, and not a diminutive thereof. But how exactly does Joseph become Joe? How does Elisabeth become Lisa, and not Elisa? Is there a rule to this? The problem I think with diminutives of English given names like Joe, is that the original name is transformed beyond recognition. Henry becoming Harry or Hal makes no sense to me. These are proper names in their own right in my opinion, and not diminutives of Henry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "augmentative." The augmentative form of Joseph would be something like 'Big Joseph.'

Comment: This is a good answer; it would be a better answer with a citation and link.

Comment: How about a link to Wikipedia? There is a whole article on [Augmentative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmentative) on Wikipedia since 2004. It clearly states what Augmentative means: "It is the opposite of a diminutive." In other words, it is the *antonym of diminutive*. But frankly, using "antonym" just to say "opposite" is a misuse of the word. In fact, I found this post with Google, by searching for "opposite of diminutive".